# Why is the integral the antiderivative of a function?

Tags: calculus

What's the demonstration that the antiderivative of a function is the integral?

Comment: It's known as the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) and you can look it up in rigorous treatments of calculus.

Comment: Any calculus text will have a proof.

Comment: I upvoted this question because in my opinion, it's a real question because some mathematicians have a demand for rigour ad just like the Jordan curve theorem, it seems so obviously true that an integral is an antiderivative but is probably actually quite difficult to give a rigorous proof of. I actually was specifically looking for a question like this so I did a Google search to find it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the intuition.  Suppose $f$ is continuous, and let
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt.
\end{equation}
Let $\Delta x > 0$ be tiny.
Then
\begin{align*}
F(x + \Delta x) - F(x) &= \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(t) \,dt.
\end{align*}
But since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is approximately constant over the 
tiny interval $[x,x + \Delta x]$.  Thus
\begin{align*}
\int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(t) \,dt &\approx \int_x^{x + \Delta x} f(x) \, dt \\
&= f(x) \int_x^{x + \Delta x} 1 \, dt \\
&= f(x) \Delta x.
\end{align*}

So we see that
\begin{align*}
& F(x + \Delta x) - F(x) \approx f(x) \Delta x \\
\implies& \frac{F(x + \Delta x) - F(x)}{\Delta x} \approx f(x).
\end{align*}

As $\Delta x \to 0$, the approximation gets better and better, so we conclude that
\begin{equation}
F'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{F(x + \Delta x) - F(x)}{\Delta x}  = f(x).
\end{equation}